# How to convert complex string input into map[string][]string?

Tags: go

I want to take a string, and convert it into a `map[string][]string`. So far I have been able to convert a string to a map[string]string like so:

```
package main

import(
 "fmt"
 "strings"
)

func main(){
    var m map[string]string
    var ss []string

    s := "Owner.RefObjectName: Owner1, Owner2, Owner3&ScheduleState:State1, State2"
    ss = strings.Split(s, "&")

    m = make(map[string]string)
    for _, pair := range ss {
        z := strings.Split(pair, ":")
        m[z[0]] = z[1]
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

this gives me a map that uses string keys and string values like this:

```
map[Owner.RefObjectName: Owner1, Owner2, Owner3 ScheduleState:State1, State2]
```

However, I need to convert the string values to a string slice, because I will need to reference the individual items like Owner1 by themselves. In short, I would like the final map to look something like this:

```
m := map[string][]string{
        "Owner.RefObjectName": {"Owner1", "Owner2", "Owner3"},
        "ScheduleState": {"State1", "State2"},
    }
```

where Owner1 Owner2 Owner3 are not in a single string, but are in a string slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split further your string along commas:

```
    var m map[string][]string
    // ...
    m = make(map[string][]string)
    for _, pair := range ss {
        obj := strings.Split(pair, ":")
        key := obj[0]
        v := strings.Split(obj[1], ",")
        m[key] = v
    }
```